# Suppress Warning in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

So, I have some VB.NET code I wrote. Something along the lines of this:

```
Public Function foo() As Object
    Select(someInt)
        Case 1
        Case 2
        Case 3
            return doStuff()
        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("Can't supply that argument to this method.")
    End Select
End Function
```

This is fine code. If someone passes an invalid argument to the method that uses this snippet, it will tell them exactly where and why something went wrong and they can fix it in no time. However… it "doesn't return a value on every code path." How can I suppress this warning?

I'd like to have this warning available on other methods, but not on this one.

[image: Warning message:]

Comment: The snippet is drastically inadequate.  But sure, I don't see it return anything from the Function either.

Comment: Updated. The function isn't the problem, I just want to know how to suppress the warning...

Comment: @JosephNields: incorrect. The function is a problem and suppressing warnings is almost never a good idea. They're there for a reason.

Comment: Try writing that function. You'll get a warning.

Comment: @JosephNields: yes, I've gotten those warnings and I fix them. In C#, they are actually errors. VB is too friendly. If you can't find the source of the warning, then your function is too big and complicated and should be broken down.

Comment: Especially since the return type is object, ignoring the warning could result in a NRE later.  (actually, as posted *most* cases do not supply a return value, only `Case 3` does).

Comment: whats is passed is not what the warning is saying - it is saying your code returns nothing in most cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB.NET doesn't work like C# with `switch` statements. You can't just stack the cases on top of each other and have fall through. There is no fall through. Instead, you must put a return in each case, or use the comma notation:

```
Public Function foo() As Object
    Dim someInt As Integer = 0
    Select Case (someInt)
        Case 1
            Return 0
        Case 2
            Return 0
        Case 3
            Return 0
        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("Can't supply that argument to this method.")
    End Select
End Function
```

Or

```
Public Function foo() As Object
    Dim someInt As Integer = 0
    Select Case (someInt)
        Case 1, 2, 3
            Return 0
        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("Can't supply that argument to this method.")
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that this is within a `Function`, correct?

You need to return a value after `doStuff()`, so something like the following (presuming your function returns an `Integer`):

```
Select(someInt)
    Case 1
    Case 2
    Case 3
        doStuff()

        Return 0
    Case Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("Can't supply that argument to this method.")
End Select
```

If this doesn't answer your question, it might help if you share with us your entire function body.

Comment: Yes, it returns a number. It's within a function. The function body is around 100 lines; but the details of the function are unimportant. All code paths are returning values or throwing ArgumentExceptions.

Comment: @JosephNields: they clearly aren't because you're getting the warning.

Answer (score -1):

Your code are inside a function.

```
Public Function NameHere(ByVal someInt as Integer) as Object
```

You need to return some value:

```
NameHere = "SomeValue"
```

Maybe you forgot this. Other solution is change Function to Sub and isn't need return value.

**EDIT**

Maybe you want to send parameter by reference:

```
Public Sub foo(ByRef someStuff as String) As Object
    Select(someInt)
        Case 1
        Case 2
        Case 3
            someStuff = doStuff()
        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("Can't supply that argument to this method.")
    End Select
End Sub
```

This avoid your Warning